# Как обратиться к storyboard из UIView класса?

Tags: ios, swift

Я создал меню при помощи xib файла. Из класса владельца я пытаюсь перейти к другому экрану.

```swift
        let feedController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Feed") as! FeedController
        feedController.feedMode = feedController.HOME_FEED
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(feedController, animated: true)
```

В UIViewController классе этот код работает и открывается другой экран. А в классе UIView пишет, что Value of type 'BottomMenu' has no member 'storyboard'.

Comment: Это логично, т.к. это UIView. Нужно чтобы это view знало о storyboard и navigationController.  Либо по-ленивому использовать NotificationCenter.

Comment: @VAndrJ Я понимаю. Что нужно передать из UIViewController, чтобы эта View узнала о сториборде?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс uiview не имеет свойства storyoard, поэтому и обратиться так вы не сможете. Просто получить доступ к storyboard можно так:

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "someStoryboardName", bundle: Bundle.init())
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "someViewControllerIdent")
```

Запушить из view можно, но, наверное, не лучший вариант.

Вы можете воспользоваться протоколам и делегированием, чтобы сообщить вашему viewController-у, что требуется совершить переход.

Объявите протокол:

```
protocol  ViewOuputDelegate{
   nextScreen()
}
```

Добавьте в ваш viewController из которого хотите совершить переход методы делегата:

```
  class SomeViewSontroller: UIViewController, ViewOuputDelegate{
   /*other code*/
   func nextScreen(){
      //Ваш код для перехода
   }
  }
```

а в вашу view переменную типа:

```
var delegate : ViewOuputDelegate?
```

При инициализации view присвойте delegate ссылку на ваш viewController и
из view можете вызывать

```
self.delegate!.nextScreen()
```

Comment: Да, про протоколы я знаю, но мне не хотелось к этому варианту прибегать вот по какой причине: это меню будет встраиваться везде, получается надо реализовывать в каждом контроллере код, который будет вызывать тот или иной экран. Хотелось просто всё лишнее оставить внутри этой вьюхи, ведь если вдруг надо будет внести изменения, то тогда придётся перелопачивать десятки файлов с контроллерами, которые имеют это меню.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю: у вас есть что-то вроде tabBar, из которого  можно по нажатию на кнопку перейти на другой экран? tabBar при этом должен быть доступен из нескольких экранов. Так?

Comment: Ну да. Раньше был стандартный таб бар, но пришлось от него отказаться и теперь в каждом контроллере будет меню похожее на таб бар, которое должно открывать вью контроллеры по принципу навигации (в смысле, закрывая один экран, возвращаешься на предыдущий). В общем я подумал, да наверное ничего страшного не будет, если я реализую через делегат.